# What is wrong in the code, I want output as [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop

My code is as follow:

```py
factors = []
num = 1

while num <= 100:
    num+=1
    if num % 10:
        break
        factors.append(num)

print(factors)
```

It is giving me the output: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: Please correct the code formatting.

Comment: This really borders on the trivial. It should take you about 1 minute to simply run the code in your head and see why it is failing to meet your expectations. Pay attention to the semantics of indentations, and to `break` (which terminates the loop entirely, not just the current iteration).

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're breaking out of the loop instead of just adding to the 'factors' list if num % 10 is 0. Remove 'break' and you should be good.

Without nitpicking further on the code (which is extremely inefficient), here's how you can quickly fix it.

```
while num <= 100: 
  num+=1 
  if num % 10 == 0: 
    factors.append(num)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = list((i for i in range(1,101))) # generate a list, 1 to 100
result = filter(lambda x1: x1%10==0,x)
```

the lambda expression means, if x1%10 == 0, return true.
filter function will use the lambda to find all items in list x that %10 equals 0.

Comment: nice approach, you just need to add ```list(filter(...))```.

Comment: Also, you don't need a list in the first line: ```x = (i for i in range(1, 101))``` generators are faster.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want to do:

```
factors, num = [], 1

while num <= 100:
    num += 1
    if num % 10 == 0:
        factors.append(num)

print(factors)
```